# How to get attribute of node with namespace using SimpleXML PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i'm trying to get the attribute info. of some fields.
This is the xml.

```html
<cfdi:Receptor nombre="JOSE GARCIA" rfc="GAJO540225EZ3"><cfdi:Domicilio calle="Conocido San Cristobal Casa 1" codigoPostal="47503" colonia="Rancho San Cristobal" estado="Jalisco" municipio="Lagos de Moreno" noExterior="S/N" noInterior="N/A" pais="Mexico" />
```

I'm trying get the values with this code (part of them), using the rules of the namespaces with simplexml, can anyone tell me how this works?

```html
$xml = simplexml_load_file("factura.xml") or die("ERROR: Cannot create SimpleXML object");
//print_r($xml);
// open MySQL connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rbp") or die ("ERROR: Cannot connect");
// process node data
// create and execute INSERT queries
foreach ($xml->cfdi->ExpedidoEn as $Receptor) {
$atributos = $Receptor->attributes();
$rfc = $atributos->rfc; //y no $product->name
$nombre_rs = $atributos->nombre;
$calle = $atributos->calle;
```

I see this error on php: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: please provide a complete but minimal valid example of your XML.

Answer (score 0):

The error-message indicates that `$xml->cfdi->ExpedidoEn` does not select what you want it to select.

You didn't post a complete valid XML, so I can only make guesses:

```
<cfdi:Receptor nombre="JOSE GARCIA" />
```

The above is a `<Receptor>` node in the `cfdi` namespace. To access nodes in a certain namespace with `Simplexml`, you can use the `children()`-method.

See example #2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php